# MongoDB: how to rename result fields in raw commands

Tags: mongodb

Given the following mongo command...

```
db.runCommand({
  "aggregate":"orders","pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"state.value":"open"}},
    {"$group":{"_id":"$currency","total":{"$sum":"$amount"}}}
  ]
})
```

... I get this result:

```
{
  "result" : [
    { "_id" : "USD", "total" : 55 },
    { "_id" : "EUR", "total" : 30 }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

In the result, is it possible to have `currency` instead of `_id`?

**EDIT**

... or event better, would it be possible to use the value of `_id` as the name for `total` like this?

```
{
  "result" : [
    { "USD" : 55 },
    { "EUR" : 30 }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

I've tried this...

```
db.runCommand({
  "aggregate":"orders",
  "pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"state.value":"open"}},
    {"$group":{"_id":"$currency","total":{"$sum":"$amount"}}},
    {"$project":{"_id":0,"$_id":"$total"}}
 ]
```

})

... but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) after group like `{"$project":{"_id":0,"currency":"$_id","total":"$total"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator stage after the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline stage and your final aggregation command should be like:

```
db.runCommand({
    "aggregate":"orders",
    "pipeline":[
        {"$match":{"state.value":"open"}},
        {"$group":{"_id":"$currency","total":{"$sum":"$amount"}}},
        {
            "$project":{
                "_id":0,
                "currency":"$_id",
                "total": 1
            }
        }
     ] 
  })
```

This suppresses the `_id` field and replaces it with the desired `currency` field to give the output:

```
{
  "result" : [
    { "currency" : "USD", "total" : 55 },
    { "currency" : "EUR", "total" : 30 }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

-- **UPDATE** --

To address your other query, MongoDB's aggregation framework does not have [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operations that can convert field values into keys. As a workaround, you could try convert the aggregation result using the [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) cursor method to iterate over the projected fields and use JavaScript's **[bracket-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** on the result object to then create desired final object:

```
var pipeline = [
        {"$match":{"state.value":"open"}},
        {"$group":{"_id":"$currency","total":{"$sum":"$amount"}}}
     ], 
    agg = db.orders.aggregate(pipeline),
    obj = {},
    result = [];

agg.forEach(function (doc){
    obj[doc._id] = doc.total;
    result.push(obj);
});
```

Output of custom result array:

```
[
    { "USD" : 55 },
    { "EUR" : 30 }
]
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get something like `{
  "result" : [
    { "USD" : 55 },
    { "EUR" : 30 }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}`?

Comment: @j3d It's not possible with the aggregation framework, but [**Map-Reduce**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) operations can produce the output.